# I made a copy of a working Django poll, however i did something wrong, because my poll does not work

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to post a value to my database. I have been looking for a long time now at a working poll app, but i cannot seem to get my poll working. Hereunder the parts used by the poll app where somewhere the error must be.

Thanks in advance for any help.

The error i get when i dont make a choice for the poll is:

**NoReverseMatch at /wedding/2/vote/ Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'wedding/(?P\d+)/vote/$']**

The error i get when i do make a choice for the poll is:

**ValueError at /wedding/2/vote/ invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from wedding import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<invitee_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
# Create your views here.
from wedding.models import Invitee, Invitee_extra

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'wedding/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'party_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the party names"""
        return Invitee.objects.all().order_by('-party_name')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Invitee
    template_name = 'wedding/detail.html'

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Invitee
    template_name = 'wedding/results.html'

def vote(request, invitee_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Invitee, pk=invitee_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.invitee_extra_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Invitee_extra.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render(request, 'wedding/detail.html', {
            'wedding': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a attendance.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.attend += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('details:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

details.html

```
<h1>name: {{ invitee.party_name }} id: {{ invitee.id }} </h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'wedding:vote' invitee.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for guests in invitee.invitee_extra_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ guests.guest }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Update gegevens" />
</form>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Invitee(models.Model):
    party_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.party_name

class Invitee_extra(models.Model):
    invitee = models.ForeignKey(Invitee)
    guest = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    attend = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.invitee
```

Full traceback when i do select a radiobutton

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/wedding/2/vote/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'wedding',
 'food',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/patrick/python/mysite/wedding/views.py" in vote
  28.         selected_choice = p.invitee_extra_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  151.         return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  298.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  590.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  608.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1198.         clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1234.                     current_negated=current_negated)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1125.         clause.add(constraint, AND)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/tree.py" in add
  104.         data = self._prepare_data(data)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in _prepare_data
  79.             value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in prepare
  352.             return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  369.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  613.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /wedding/2/vote/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

and the fulltraceback if i dont make a choice:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/wedding/1/vote/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'wedding',
 'food',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/patrick/python/mysite/wedding/templates/wedding/detail.html, error at line 5
   Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'wedding/(?P<invitee_id>\\d+)/vote/$']
   1 : <h1>name: {{ invitee.party_name }} id: {{ invitee.id }} </h1>


   2 : 


   3 : {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}


   4 : 


   5 : <form action=" {% url 'wedding:vote' invitee.id %} " method="post">


   6 : {% csrf_token %}


   7 : {% for guests in invitee.invitee_extra_set.all %}


   8 :     <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />


   9 :     <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ guests.guest }}</label><br />


   10 : {% endfor %}


   11 : <input type="submit" value="Update gegevens" />


   12 : </form>

Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/patrick/python/mysite/wedding/views.py" in vote
  33.             'error_message': "You didn't select a attendance.",
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  169.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  447.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  433.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  509.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  429.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /wedding/1/vote/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'wedding/(?P<invitee_id>\\d+)/vote/$']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your vote view, if the submission is not valid, you re-render the template but you don't pass the Invitee to it - or rather you do, but you call it `wedding` rather than `invitee`. So when the template tries to calculate the URL of the vote submission for the invitee, it can't find the if value to use. You need to be sure to pass the data with the correct names.

Note this would have been easier to debug if you'd provided more information about the error, such as the full traceback and what you did leading up to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the full tracebacks. I am pretty sure its something dumb. But i cannot find it myself. Hopefully i learn something to never forget.